# Definition of "structure"

Tags: group-theory, soft-question, terminology, definition

I'm studying group theory, and the instructor in the lecture videos I'm watching just referring to groups as occurring as structure-preserving bijections. I know it makes sense to talk of "linear structure" (the ability to take linear combinations), but I wasn't sure if it's fully correct to refer to $S_n$ as "bijections preserving set structure." A permutation $\sigma \in S_n$ certainly preserves the set $\{1, \ldots, n\}$, but is it correct to call this "structure"?

Comment: Usually "structure-preserving bijections" mean maps between two groups, which are a group isomorphism. They are bijective and preserve the structures. So we can view these groups as the same (more precisely "isomorphic", not the same). But here we are talking just about the definition of the symmetric group.

Comment: I'm curious, in that lecture, were the groups "acting" on some other mathematical object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Saunders Mac Lane in "Structure in mathematics", a mathematical structure is an object that fulfils certain axioms. In group theory, for example, the axioms for a certain group $G$, under the abstract operation of multiplication are:

- Associativity.
- Existence of a neutral element.
- For each element, the existence of an inverse element.

Since you are taking a course in group theory, I won't spell these out. If you want, I can, though.

**Reference:**

Mac Lane, S. (1996). Structure in mathematics. Philosophia Mathematica, 4(2), 174-183.

**Edit**

I highly recommend the paper. It is a fantastic read and by no means technical.